# Link to onedrive file opens without logged in

Tags: onedrive

I have made an Outlook free account. With this account I have 5GB free storage on opendrive and the use of Ms Office web applications. I made an online excel file and I take the link to it. I realize something very strange. I can use this link to open the file from anywhere without the need to logged in to the free account!!! I go to another pc that never had been logged in to the free account and the file is opened!!! Have I misunderstood something? This is a security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared links default to "Anyone with the link".

It's up to you to restrict access.

[image]

See [MS-KB - Share OneDrive files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-onedrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07)

Comment: Sometimes I feel that stackexchange is only for elite people. I don't understand why negative votes for my question. I am in the road to alternative forums.

Comment: You'll never know who or why downvoted, nor will they see this comment - they're long gone. You just need a thick skin to participate in any online environment with voting. btw, this is not a forum.